# html5 div inside a context of canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I started using html5 canvas object on my web site and I want to draw rectangles (or other shapes according to my application) on the canvas. I can write text on the rectangles using the context object.

What I am trying to do is that I want to put a div element in the rectangle. So I can semantically work with my objects on the canvas like put a paragraph and a border inside the rectangle etc., storing some trivial data in the objects. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing goes inside the `canvas` tag except for elements that would be displayed if the browser doesn't support HTML5 and canvas.  If you want to display regular HTML elements in a DIV, you could simply position it absolutely so that it floats above the canvas:

```
<canvas height="100" width="200" style="position:absolute;left:10;top:10"></canvas>

<div id="yourDiv" style="position:absolute;left:20;top:20">Your content</div>
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: for example I have drawn 4 rectangles inside the canvas, I want to store some information on/in them for example the name of the rectangle, the description of the rectangle, some id that it corresponds to a row in db table. Can I store that detailed information in an element of canvas? You could do that in WPF for example. Or do I have to store them on Javascript?

Comment: The canvas is used for drawing so I don't think there's any metadata that you can associate with any of the elements that you draw.  You would have to do that in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Older Browser not supporting canvas should show those divs. As you can easily try out, other browsers will store the div in your dom tree, but not show it. So you should be able to do some dom semantics, but you'll have to paint them on your canvas for browsers supporting it.

If you want to show the divs and paint onto them using canvas, you'll have to use positioning to show them over each other.